# Is there a way to array an object along a few faces?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, faces

Of course, objects can be arrayed along a curve, but I was wondering if there was a way to array them along a series of faces. I'm gonna be adding details to my Titanic model, and I'm wanting to array objects along the hull and walls, but most of them are curved (at least slightly) so a straight array just won't do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Shrinkwrap Modifier* to the curve, but if you are planing to add details to a mesh you already have, I'll recommend to:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> enter edit mode, chose edge select, select the edges
2. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it, then press <kbd>P</kbd> separate selected.
3. With this you'll have made a new object copy of the selected edges.
4. <kbd>tab</kbd> to go back object mode, select the new object, and convert it
   to a curve
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> curve from mesh.
6. You can also use parent object, on the property panel select
   verts on the parent object ,"the curve or the line you chose".

[image]

Comment: That's the way I have been doing it, and I suppose I can continue using this method for the rivets. I'm also trying to figure out the joggling effect of the hull's plates (the seams along the horizontal parts of the plating).
Photo reference:
http://www.travellinghistorian.com/vicp45gig.jpg

Diagram reference (top diagram is what I'm referring to):
https://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/community/attachments/demonstration-jpg.40384/

Comment: i dont understand whats your goal, but if you need it to be parented to a face,  select [face] instead of [verts] in the property panel at right side.
see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNjk83mCVu8